# What is wrong with my projection

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers to plot a point on a map; the point should be located in the UK; but keeps appearing in the middle of the ocean (0,0). I have check my projection and I think this is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I use to define the map in OpenLayers3

```
var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [raster, vector_layer,vectorLayer],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([51.714090, -0.413285], 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:4326'),
            zoom: 2,
                projection: 'EPSG:900913',
            displayProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the XY and source.destination CRS flipped in your transform. Also, code `900913` is deprecated, use `3857` instead.

```
center: ol.proj.transform([-0.413285, 51.714090], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
```

Comment: This has just flipped the map, it is still not centering on the coordinates.

Comment: Edited my answer. The points are defined as (X, Y) so that would correspond to (longitude, latitude).

Answer (score 2):

From my reading of the [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.0/apidoc/ol.proj.html#transform) it looks like you have the source and target of your transform reversed, so you are transforming from 900913 to 4326 rather than from 4316 to 3957 which is what you need.

So change

```
center: ol.proj.transform([51.714090, -0.413285], 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:4326'),
```

to

```
center: ol.proj.transform([51.714090, -0.413285], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
```

and all should be well.

**EDIT**

As ThomasG77 points out you should use the more recent construct:

```
ol.proj.fromLonLat([51.714090, -0.413285])
```

Comment: Although your answer is valid, you should better use the more recent way with `ol.proj.fromLonLat([51.714090, -0.413285])`. Just convenient because syntax more simple. You may edit your answer to add this alternative.